# why cv2.bitwise_and function of opencv-python returns four element array on single scalar value

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to understand `cv2.bitwise_and` function of opencv-python. So I tried it as:

```
import cv2
cv2.bitwise_and(1,1)
```

above code returns

```
array([[1.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])
```

I don't understand why it returns this.

[Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) says :

`dst(I) = src1(I) ^ src2(I) if mask(I) != 0`

according to this output should be single value 1. where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is a bit vague in this aspect, and it will take some digging through both source, as well as docs to properly explain what's happening.

First of all -- scalars. In context of data types, we have a `cv::Scalar`, which is actually a specialization of template [`cv::Scalar_`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d1/da0/classcv_1_1Scalar__.html). It represents a 4-element vector, and derives from [`cv::Vec`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d6/dcf/classcv_1_1Vec.html) -- a template representing a fixed size vector, which is again a special case of [`cv::Matx`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/de/de1/classcv_1_1Matx.html), a class representing small fixed size matrices.

That's scalar the data type, however in the context of the `bitwise_and` (and related functions), the concept what is and isn't a scalar is much looser -- the function in fact is not aware that gave it an instance of `cv::Scalar`.

If you look at the [signature of the function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14), you'll notice that the inputs are [`InputArray`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html)s. So the inputs are **always** arrays, but it's possible that some of their properties differ (kind, element type, size, dimensionality, etc.).

The specific [check in the code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/69103a9fab13d81c41f37806a37ff56c37dae204/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp#L183) verifies that size, type and kind match. If that's the case (and in your scenario it is), the operation `dst(I) = src1(I) ^ src2(I) if mask(I) != 0` runs.

Otherwise it will check whether one of the input arrays represents a scalar. It uses function [`checkScalar`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/17233c687e2d51010dab2587f2532a460ccdb4b6/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp#L230) to do that, and the return statement says most of it:

```
return sz == Size(1, 1)
    || sz == Size(1, cn) || sz == Size(cn, 1)
    || (sz == Size(1, 4) && sc.type() == CV_64F && cn <= 4);
```

- Anything that has size 1 x 1
- Anything that size 1 x `cn` or `cn` x 1 (where `cn` is the number of channels if the other input array).
- Anything that has size 1 x 4 and elements are 64bit floating point values, but only when the other input array has 4 or fewer channels.

The last case matches both the default `cv::Scalar` (which, as we have seen earlier, is a `cv::Matx<double,4,1>`), as well as `cv::Mat(4,1,CF_64F)`.

---

As an intermission, let's test some of what we learned above.

Code:

```
cv::Scalar foo(1), bar(1);
cv::Mat result;
cv::bitwise_and(foo, bar, result);
std::cout << result << '\n';
std::cout << "size : " << result.size() << '\n';
std::cout << "type==CV_64FC1 : " << (result.type() == CV_64FC1 ? "yes" : "no") << '\n';
```

Output:

```
[1;
 0;
 0;
 0]
size : [1 x 4]
type==CV_64FC1 : yes
```

---

Having covered the underlying C++ API, let's look at the Python bindings. The generator that creates the wrappers for Python API is fairly complex, so let's skip that, and instead inspect a relevant snippet of what it generates for `bitwise_and`:

```
    using namespace cv;

    {
    PyObject* pyobj_src1 = NULL;
    Mat src1;
    PyObject* pyobj_src2 = NULL;
    Mat src2;
    PyObject* pyobj_dst = NULL;
    Mat dst;
    PyObject* pyobj_mask = NULL;
    Mat mask;

    const char* keywords[] = { "src1", "src2", "dst", "mask", NULL };
    if( PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kw, "OO|OO:bitwise_and", (char**)keywords, &pyobj_src1, &pyobj_src2, &pyobj_dst, &pyobj_mask) &&
        pyopencv_to(pyobj_src1, src1, ArgInfo("src1", 0)) &&
        pyopencv_to(pyobj_src2, src2, ArgInfo("src2", 0)) &&
        pyopencv_to(pyobj_dst, dst, ArgInfo("dst", 1)) &&
        pyopencv_to(pyobj_mask, mask, ArgInfo("mask", 0)) )
    {
        ERRWRAP2(cv::bitwise_and(src1, src2, dst, mask));
        return pyopencv_from(dst);
    }
    }
    PyErr_Clear();
```

We can see that parameters that correspond to `InputArray` or `OutputArray` are loaded into a `cv::Mat` instance. Let's look at the part of [`pyopencv_to`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/17233c687e2d51010dab2587f2532a460ccdb4b6/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L224) that corresponds to your scenario:

```
if( PyInt_Check(o) )
{
    double v[] = {static_cast<double>(PyInt_AsLong((PyObject*)o)), 0., 0., 0.};
    m = Mat(4, 1, CV_64F, v).clone();
    return true;
}
```

A `cv::Mat(4, 1, CV_64F)` (recall from earlier that this fits the test for scalar) containing the input integer cast to double, with the remaining 3 position padded with zeros.

Since no destination is provided, a `Mat` will be allocated automatically, of the same size and type as inputs. On return to Python, the `Mat` will become a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says clearly that the function performs the operations `dst(I) = src1(I) ^ src2(I) if mask(I) != 0` if the inputs are two **arrays** of the same size.

So try:

```
import numpy as np  # Opecv works with numpy arrays
import cv2

a = np.uint8([1])
b = np.uint8([1])
cv2.bitwise_and(a, b)
```

That code returns:

```
array([[1]], dtype=uint8)
```

That is a one dimensional array containing the number 1.

The documentation also mentions that the operation can be done with an array and a scalar, but not with two scalars, so the input `cv2.bitwise_and(1,1)` is not correct.

Comment: that should throw error then. wonder why that kind of output.

Comment: @krishna The thing is, it's not an error, yours is a valid case of 2 arrays of the same size/type/etc. It's just not that clear, especially without understanding some details about the underlying C++ implementation and the generated Python bindings.

Comment: @DanMašek a noobish question where can I find source code for python bindings of opencv. I can find only opecv c++ source code when I find python opencv source code.

Comment: @krishna The implementation of the Python bindings is generated by scripts in OpenCV module `python` at compilation time. So you need to compile OpenCV with python enabled, and then look for file `pyopencv_generated_funcs.h` (that's the one I used, there are few others with similar prefix). There's also a [short tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html) about the topic.